# Performance Optimisation Techniques for getSystemService() in Android 2.3

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-service, android-2.3-gingerbread

In my app, I am accessing Android's system services quite often in many classes, so I began to wonder what would be the best approach to access Android system services.

I am currently storing the returned system service in a singleton object. Is this the right approach for optimising the access to system services? What is the best approach to access system services if it is referenced quite frequently in the application?

Example class to access AudioManager system service through singleton:

```
public enum Audio
{
    INSTANCE;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    public void set(Context context)
    {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    public AudioManager getAudioManager()
    {
        return mAudioManager;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you really *need* to optimize away the `getSystemService()` calls?

Comment: That's why I asked this question because I do not know what Google developers have done to optimise Android system service access in Android 2.3. Most importantly if I should leave the Singleton class, remove it, call directly getSystemService() or add other performance optimisation techniques.

Comment: Just call `getSystemService()`. If you need the same object for several things in a method, keep it in a variable. Either local or a member of the class in question if you need it all the time. If you are interested in the implementation of the method you can look it up here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29